# what exactly is cumulative CPU time

Tags: linux

While working with a tomcat process in Linux we observed that the time field shows 
5506:34 ( cumulative CPU time ) . While exploring this is the CPU percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process.

Since this is a Java process we also observed that memory was almost full and needed a restart.

My Question is what exactly is this Cumulative CPU time. Why does this specific process taking more CPU time when there are other process too ?

Answer (score -1):

the total time the cpu spends on a process. If the process uses more threads, these are cumulated.

Comment: ... what? Your sentence doesnt make any sense whatsoever - i recommend doing some research on the topic : [Thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) before you start accusing people